# Scrollbar appears when I want to adapt a grid to the viewport

Tags: html, css, grid, viewport, cover

This is driving me crazy. Just trying to fit this grid into the entire page with height and vw value. But when I write it on CSS it appears the scroll bar!!! How do I fix this?
Here's the html. It's just a basic thing but I don't know what to do!

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr) 0.1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
}

.b {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.c {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 5 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.name {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 7 / 7;
}

.contact {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 7 / 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <p>Contact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset your margin for `html` and `body`. If you still would like to keep padding, you can give it to your `.grid` class but reduce the equal value from height.

```css
html, 
body {
  margin: 0
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr) 0.1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 96vh;
  padding: 2vh
}

.a {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
}

.b {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.c {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 5 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.name {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 7 / 7;
}

.contact {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 7 / 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <p>Contact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```